# Инжект полей без конструктора c Dagger 2

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger2

На сайте с документации к Dagger 2 есть следующий пример кода и слова:

```
class CoffeeMaker {
  @Inject Heater heater;
  @Inject Pump pump;

  ...
}
```

> If your class has @Inject-annotated fields but no @Inject-annotated
>   constructor, Dagger will inject those fields if requested, but will
>   not create new instances. Add a no-argument constructor with the
>   @Inject annotation to indicate that Dagger may create instances as
>   well.

Что это значит? Т.е., если конструктора с @Inject не будет, как Dagger будет инжектить эти поля "if requested, but will not create new instances"?

Т.е. насколько я понимаю, тут:

```
class CoffeeMaker @Inject (Heater heater) {
}
```

если объект Heater раньше не был создан - dagger создаст новый его объект (условно говоря, `heater = Heater()`), если же его объект сейчас используется другим классом, то получим тут ссылку на этот же обьект, что использует другой класс  (условно говоря, `heater = heaterObj`).
А что будет тут?

```
class CoffeeMaker {
   @Inject Heater heater;
}
```

В случае, если объект Heater раньше не был создан?
И в случае, если такой его обьект сейчас используется другим классом?

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае нужно явно инжектить. Пример инжекта полей в Fragment() на андроид:

```
class AlbumsFragment: Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mAdapter: AlbumsListAdapter

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: CustomViewModelFactory

    lateinit var viewModel: AlbumViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(false)

        (activity?.application as App).getComponent().inject(this)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(AlbumViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.setAdapter(mAdapter)

        mAdapter.setActivity(activity as AppCompatActivity)
    }
}
```

Интерфейс Component:

```
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(fragment: AlbumsFragment)

}
```

> Что это значит? Т.е., если конструктора с @Inject не будет, как Dagger будет инжектить эти поля "if requested, but will not create new instances"?

Инициализация полей происходит после метода:

```
(activity?.application as App).getComponent().inject(this)
```

Т.е. если не будет этого вызова, поля не будут проинициализированы.

> В случае, если объект Heater раньше не был создан? И в случае, если такой его обьект сейчас используется другим классом?

Если в Module() поля не обозначены как синглтоны, то будут созданы новые объекты, а если обозначены, то будет инжектится один экземпляр для всех классов.